# How to apply gradient colors on UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, gradient

I am trying to apply [Gradient Colors](https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon#gradient-colors) of [Chameleon](https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon) library on UINavigationBar. [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial) tutorial suggests that we can apply theme to all instances of UINavigationBar by using `UINavigationBar.appearance()`. So this means that I can do something like following to set the gradient:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(gradientStyle:UIGradientStyle.LeftToRight,  
  withFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UINavigationBar.appearance().frame.width, UINavigationBar.appearance().frame.height), 
  andColors:[UIColor.flatMagentaColorDark(), UIColor.flatLimeColor()])
```

But the problem is that I am not able to get the height and the width of the UINavigationBar instance. It is required for `withFrame` parameter in the above code. Is there any way to apply gradients to all instances in one shot?

Comment: Does this code work if you set the color to something simple like red?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
gradientLayer.frame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds

let color1 = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor as CGColorRef
let color2 = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor as CGColorRef
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0]
 self.navigationController!.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

You can add more colors by adding them to the `gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]` array

Comment: I'm running iOS 9.3 and notice that this `gradientLayer` ends up hiding the back button text (but not the chevron). After loading I loop through the `UINavigationBar` sublayers and the gradient layer is always above the text layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to apply gradient colors on `UINavigationBar`using `Chameleon`

```
 let primaryGradientColor: UIColor = {
    let sizeLength = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height * 2
    let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeLength, 64)
    let colors = [UIColor.flatMagentaColorDark(), UIColor.flatLimeColor()]
    return GradientColor(.LeftToRight, frame: defaultNavigationBarFrame, colors: colors)
}()

Chameleon.setGlobalThemeUsingPrimaryColor(primaryGradientColor,
                                              withSecondaryColor: UIColor.clearColor(),
                                              andContentStyle: UIContentStyle.Light)
```